# Why does python say there is no attribute called connect to pymysql?

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to connect to my database using python code but when trying to do so an error is produced.

This is the code:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db = "sampledB")

myCursor = conn.cursor()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pymysql' has no attribute 'connect'
```

The error is directed to line 3. I would like it to connect to my database so any help is appreciated.
I am trying to learn mySQL, HTML, and Python; therefore, I would be grateful if someone could direct me to a course or a place where I can learn.
I'm particularly interested in user input, sanitization, and validation.

Comment: basic example that might help: http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Comment: When I try to import `pymysql.cursors` it says that there is no module as such and that pymysql isn't a package.

Comment: I hate to ask, but is pymysql installed?

Comment: try: `pip install pymysql` from command line

Comment: If you're on windows open a command prompt and type py -m pip install pymysql, python can get a little tricky if you have more then one version installed, or if you're in linux trying to install and run as root from a user account.

Comment: Is there anything named `pymysql` (.py, .pyc or a folder) in your project?

Comment: I have run that command and when I go back it doesn't work

Comment: @KlausD. Yes. It is the file name.

Comment: Rename it! The file has priority over the library you want to import.

Comment: A simple mistake I've made a few times, I was wondering why it didn't give an import error, that should have been a giveaway.